# What's the most succinct syntax to preserve only specific keys from a large JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

In other words, I want to clean objects by dropping most of their keys.

Say a third party API returns JSON with a large number of of attributes you don't care about.

```
obj = {
  name: ...,
  id: ...,
  description: ...,
  blah: ...,
  bloop: ...,
  blip: ...,
  ... 12 others
}
```

But you're only interested in, say, `id` and `name`.

I know there's <s>spread syntax</s> object destructuring that allows me to put these into separate variables.

```
const { id, name } = obj
```

Is there a way to transform `obj` into a new object that looks like the following without explicitly accessing every key and value and making an object out of those?

```
newObj = {
  id: ...,
  name: ...
}
```

I'm curious if there's a one-liner I can put into `map` to transform a whole array of these objects.

Comment: That's not spread syntax, that's object destructuring.

Comment: Oops, that's what I meant.

Comment: No problem. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax (In case you wanted it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just destructure the wanted properties and use short hand properties for the object.

```
result = array.map(({ id, name }) => ({ id, name }));
```